# string contains inside of attribute of list

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to display contact which has id = 'asdf-123' from List of class Contact which have attributes [id, name, phone, dob].

i can do it by doing

```
bool isContainId = false;
String testId = 'asdf-123';

contacts.foreach((contact) {
  if (contact.id == testId) {
    isContainId = true;
  }
});
```

however, is there any better way of doing it. something like `.contains`. please help!.

Comment: If you want to lighten your code, you can do this as a function of Contact.

Comment: thank you, i will do that if i don't find any alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Contains` can not work with custom models in dart, you have to traverse through each object for this kind of operation.

```
bool isContainId = false;
String testId = 'asdf-123';

isContainId = contacts.firstWhere((contact)=> contact.id == testId, orElse: (){isContainId = false;}) != null;
```

UPDATE:

```
class CustomModel {
  int id;
  CustomModel({this.id});
}

void main() {
  List<CustomModel> all = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    all.add(CustomModel(id: i));
  }
  bool isContainId = false;
  isContainId = all.firstWhere((contact)=> contact.id == 5, orElse: (){isContainId = false;}) != null;
  print(isContainId);
}
```

Comment: this is a type of solution i am looking for, but it returns me `Bad state: no element` error

Comment: I am able to fix it by using
```
bool isFound = contacts.firstWhere((contact) => contact.id == testId, orElse: () => null) != null;
```

Comment: i just add `orElse` parameter to firstWhere and it works like charm, thank you, i think you can update your answer, then i can mark as answer